# Is this a correct proof of why $\gcd(a,b) = \gcd(b, a- b)$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, alternative-proof

I have a proof but I wasn't sure if it was correct (or how rigorous it is). I will point out what worries me.

Let $D_a = \{ d : d \mid a\}$ (i.e. all elements that divide $a$) and similarly $D_b = \{ d : d \mid b\}$. Therefore we can define $\gcd(a,b)$ as follows:

$$\gcd(a,b) = \max(D_a \cap D_b)$$

Consider $D_{a-b} = \{ d : d \mid (a-b)\}$. I claim $D_{a-b} = D_a \cap D_b$. Every element that divides $a$ and $b$ should also divide the difference between $a - b$. i.e. $\forall d_{a,b} \in D_a \cap D_b$, $d_{a,b} \mid a - b$.This means that $D_{a - b}$ has at least every element that divides $a$ and $b$ i.e. $D_a \cap D_b \subseteq D_{a-b}$. I claim that $D_{a - b} \subseteq D_a \cap D_b$. Why? Consider an element $d' \in D_{a - b}$ but that doesn't divide both $a$ and $b$ but does divide the difference. Obviously, it doesn't make sense because for it to divide the difference it has to divide $a$ and $b$. Hence, the common divisors of $a$ and $b$ didn't change. Thus, $D_{a-b} = D_{a} \cap D_{b}$.

Now with that information at hand consider $\gcd(b,a-b) = \max (D_{a} \cap D_{a - b}) =  \max( D_{a} \cap D_{a} \cap D_{b} ) = \max ( D_a \cap D_b ) $ which is the same as the definition of $\gcd(a,b)$.

So I was wondering if this proof was correct or if there was a way to explain it in a better or more concise way. It seems overly complicated but it actually expresses a super simple idea.

---

I think I have fixed my proof:

The idea of the proof is to show that the common divisors of $a$ and $b$ are the same as the common divisors of $b$, $a-b$ and therefore, since they share the same common divisors they share the same greatest common divisor. 
For this we first show that if $d \mid a$ and $d \mid b $ then $ d \mid a - b$. This is clear since if $a = x_a d$ and $b = x_b d$ then $a - b = (x_a - x_b)d$. Thus, $d \mid a - b$. So every divisor of $a$ and $b$ divides $b$ and $a - b$. For the other direction, consider an element $d'$ that divides both $b$ and $a - b$. If $d'$ divides $b$ and $b-a$ then it divides any linear combination of them, in particular, it divides the difference of them. i.e. $d' \mid a - (b -a) $ thus, $d' \mid a$. Therefore, every element that divides $b$ and $b -a$ also divides $a$ and $b$. Hence, $a, b$ and $b, b-a$ share the same common divisors and in particular they share the largest common divisor.

Comment: Way too much notation!  And of course $D_{a-b}$ is not equal to $D_a\cap D_b$.  You had good intuition. Why not write a proof without symbols at all, except of $a$ and $b$?

Comment: Hi Charlie!  Please note that the correct way to format the GCD function in TeX is **\gcd** and not just *gcd*.

Comment: @JoseArnaldoBebitaDris oh wasn't aware of that. Thanks! Is that because GCD has a special meaning in mathematics or why is that the case?

Comment: $\gcd(a,b)$ is the greatest common divisor of $a$ and $b$.  So for example, if $a = 36$ and $b = 54$, then $\gcd(a,b)=18$.

Comment: @CharlieParker If you write gcd without \, Tex treats it as variables g, c and d; with \, it treats it as the abbreviation for "greatest common divisor" (also it looks different). Likewise for limit, maximum, infimum etc.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I will try and will update you once I have a better expressed proof. Meanwhile, I'm sort of surprised that $D_{a -b} \neq D_a \cap D_b$. I thought that every number that divided $a$ and $b$ should divide the difference also but if it divides the difference, shouldn't it also divide $a$ and $b$ individually, hence the equality? Or maybe I am completely wrong.

Comment: $2$ divides $11-7$, but it doesn't divide $7$ or $11$. In other words, $2\in D_{11-7}$ but $2\notin D_7\cap D_{11}$.

Comment: @AkivaWeinbergercolumbus interesting. Now I see I was wrong with the counter example, but what was the intuition for knowing this? Clearly my intuition in that detail was wrong and I'd be awesome to fix it, not just to know I was wrong. Thnx for the help though!

Comment: @CharlieParker If you're not sure if something is true, a good idea is to just try examples. If it's false, you might find a counterexample; if it's true, you might better understand why.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I think I have fixed my proof. I included the new one in my question. What do you think about it now?

Comment: It is fine. The amount of detail to give is not well-defined. I would say it is obvious that any integer that divides $a$ and $b$ diviides $b$ and $a-b$. Also, any integer that divides $b$ and $a-b$ divides $a$ and $b$. So the set of common divisors of $\dots$.  Two points about your new proof: (i) It is understandable and (ii) it is right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof has one flaw: "Consider an element $d′∈D_{a−b}$ but that doesn't divide both $a$ and $b$ but does divide the difference. Obviously, it doesn't make sense because for it to divide the difference it has to divide $a$ and $b$.". Consider $d'=8$, $a=9$ and $b=1$.
The issue is that the statement $D_{a - b} = D_a \cap D_b$ is false. Instead, you'll want to prove that $D_{a - b} \cap D_a= D_a \cap D_b$.

How to do so:

> Let $d$ be a divisor of both $a$ and $b$. Then there is $k$ and $k'$ verifying $a=dk$ and $b=dk'$. Therefore $(a-b)=d(k-k')$ i.e. $d$ divides $(a-b)$.
> Then let $d$ be a divisor of both $a$ and $a-b$. Then it must divide their sum, so $d$ divides $b$.

By the way, there is minor writing issue:
One should write "$\gcd(b,a-b) = \max (D_{a} \cap D_{a - b}) $" instead of  "$\gcd(b,a-b) = D_{a} \cap D_{a - b} $", since the gcd is a integer and not a set.

Comment: Does that mean to fix my proof we need to say $D_{a - b} \cap D_a = D_a \cap D_b$ hence, $a$ and $b$ have the same common divisors as $a$ and $a - b$ and therefore, since they have the same common divisors they share the same greatest common divisor?

Comment: That's indeed my suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go for a simpler notation: $D(a,b)=$ the set of common divisors of $a$ and $b$.

Of course, $\gcd(a,b) = \max D(a,b)$.

The result you want follows from $D(a,b) = D(a-b,b)$, which is easy to prove.

Comment: Perhaps you meant $\gcd(a,b) = \max\{D(a,b)\}$ instead?

Comment: @JoseArnaldoBebitaDris, yes, fixed, thanks